# Match All Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having difficulty with writing an SQL query for my application. Below shows a screenshot of some of the tables in my database.

[image]
[image]

Please let me explain how a section of my application works, and then I can show you the problem I am having with my SQL query.

A User can create an application form on my system (`dbo.Form`). An application form consists of several sections, one of those sections is Employment History (`dbo.FormEmployment`). An employment record includes details like employer name, start date etc, but also a gradeID. A User can add one or more employment records to the table `dbo.FormEmployment`.

A system administrator can add a Shift (`dbo.Shift`) to the system, and also then assign Grades to a Shift. These Grades are recorded in the `dbo.ShiftGrade` table. A Shift can be assigned 1 or more Grades, i.e. it could be assigned 1,2,3,4 or 5 Grades.

When the system administrator has added the Shift and Shift Grades, I then want to perform an SQL query to return a list of Users whose Grades match that of the Grades assigned to a Shift (remember the User adds their Grade when they add an employment record).

I have written the following SQL query which works, however, the issue with this query is that it returns a list of Users, that have any Grade that matches that of the Grades assigned to a Shift.

```
SELECT   u.userID, u.userTypeID, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, u.password, 
u.contactNumber, u.organisationID, u.emailVerificationCode, u.mobileVerificationCode, 
u.userStatusID, u.AddedBy, u.AddedDate, u.ModifiedBy, u.ModifiedDate
FROM     [User] u
--Check Grades Match
WHERE    u.userID IN
     (
     SELECT f.locumID
     FROM   dbo.Form f, dbo.FormEmployment emp
     WHERE  f.formID = emp.formID
     AND    emp.statusID = 101
     AND    emp.workYN = 1
     AND    emp.gradeID IN (
             select gradeID from dbo.ShiftGrade where shiftID = @p0
             )
     )
```

You can see I am using the IN statement to do this. However, I only want to return a list of Users who can match exactly the same Grades that have been assigned to a Shift. Therefore, if a Shift has been assigned 3 Grades, then I want a List of Users who also have the exact same three Grades to be returned.

I apologise for the lengthy post, I just thought it would be better explained this way.
Any feedback or help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shortly, you need to `join` tables.

Comment: How are `User` and `Grade` related? Post a screenshot of fully expanded database scheme.

Comment: @abatishchev locumID in dbo.Form is linked to userID in dbo.User. When a User creates a new record in dbo.FormEmployment, they also select a gradeID. This new record then belongs to the User. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sure, it makes, but please post a new screenshot though

Comment: What is the difference between `dbo.ShiftGrade.shiftGradeID` and `dbo.ShiftGrade.shiftID`?

Comment: @abatishchev dbo.ShiftGrade.shiftGradeID is the Primary Key field for the table dbo.ShiftGrade. dbo.ShiftGrade.shiftID is the Foreign Key which is linked to the Primary Key in dbo.Shift.shiftID

Comment: Okay, makes sense. So where is `dbo.ShiftGrade.gradeId` referenced? Do you have also `dbo.Grade`, and ShiftGrade is a many-to-many relationship container?

Comment: @abatishchev dbo.ShiftGrade.gradeId referenced inside the IN statement of my SQL, ie, IN ( select ShiftGrade.gradeId from dbo.ShiftGrade where shiftID = @p0)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13519/discussion-between-abatishchev-and-tgriffiths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select u.*
from dbo.Users u
join dbo.Form f on u.? = f.formId
join dbo.FormEmployment fe on fe.formId = f.formId
join dbo.Grade g on g.gradeId =  fe.gradeId
join dbo.ShiftGrade shg on shg.gradeId =g.gradeId
join dbo.Shift sh on sh.shiftId = shg.shiftId
where
    sh.shiftId = -- recently added shift id
and g.gradeId == -- recently added grade id
```